# Can matcaps be used for all objects and not just selected objects?

Tags: 3d-view, matcaps

### *Update, in 2.71 and newer, there is no longer a limitation*

I like to use Matcaps as they greatly improve the viewport performance and are good when editing to get an idea of what the object looks like textured. However, if I have multiple objects, only the selected object shows the Matcap.

Is it possible to use Matcaps for all objects, and not just the one selected?

Comment: First question first: what are 'Matcaps'?

Comment: @Gwenn Matcaps allow the use of a set of predefined GLSL shaders in the 3d view without rendering. They somewhat match a set of materials though they do not take user textures and are not perfect renditions. A full render should still be used to check appearance.

Comment: I seem to have the opposite problem with Blender 2.73.  When I turn Matcap on, all objects are shaded with the same Matcap texture.  For sculpting, I only want the selected object shaded with Matcap (as in numerous tutorials).  How can I get it to just do Matcap shading for the selected object in Sculpt mode?

Comment: @Chuck you should open a new question for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by adding a new material and then adding an image texture to it, load in a matcap *([grab some here from Blender's online src](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/trunk/blender/release/datafiles/matcaps/))* or [*here from zBrush's free library*](http://pixologic.com/zbrush/downloadcenter/library/) and under *Mapping* in the texture tab set the coordinates to *Normal*.

Now in your scene, in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel under *Display*, change *Shading* to *GLSL*, switch the viewport shading to *Texture* with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and add a *Hemi* lamp to your scene. Any objects with the material will now show as such.

*To have all objects use matcaps just temporarily assign that material until you need to render etc.* If you have multiple objects, you can quickly do this by selecting all the ones you want to apply it to then selecting the one with the material applied already and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and choose *Materials*.

[image]

Comment: is this still the same process in blender 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Under *Viewport Shading* tab select *Random* in the *Colors* section.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant in newer versions of Blender (it's 9 years old!) since nowadays switching to _MatCap_ applies the same matcap to all objects. And your answer does not provide a solution, since _Random_ gives random colors to objects, which actually makes all matcaps tinted slightly different instead of making them all the same. And even if someone still uses such an old version where the matcap only worked on selected objects, the _Random_ feature wouldn't be available to them because it was first introduced in version 2.80.