# Matcap shading on blender 2.76

Tags: shaders

How can I get Blender to show Matcap shading for object on blender 2.76?[image]

Comment: Same as in 2.71 - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16339/how-to-apply-matcap-materials-for-sculpting-in-blender-2-71

Answer (score 1):

In the **Properties** side panel, Shortcut key **N** > Shading menu ...

[image]

Comment: thanks but my problem is nothing happen when i apply the matcap.