# Is there a way to use a separate texture for object reflections?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, matcaps

I've been experimenting with using the default matcap textures in render mode (using Normal or Reflection mapping), and it looks pretty good. However, I'd like to use them as a "reflection map," so that objects with mirror properties use the texture rather than the actual world. Is there a way to do that easily?

EDIT: Probably should've specified that I'm using Blender Render rather than Cycles.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2030/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/554/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to "fake" reflections by simply blending the reflection texture with the material (Mix + Color: <1 + Coordinates: Reflection).

[image: texture pane]

[image: render result]

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** take any good HDR texture and put it in Environment node for your glossy shader.

[image]

For Internal:

[image]

Comment: That's helpful, but I forgot to specify that I wasn't using Cycles.