# How can i get 'shining' borders to a material in Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm using Blender Render right now and i'm trying to achieve something like this picture:

[image]

*With that i mean, if its possible or is there a way to render the object with Blender Render, but adding those kind of 'shining borders'? (circled in the picture)*

**I need to make that kind of material, is there any setup to do it?**

Thanks in regard.

Comment: This is in large part lighting, however I think some of it is based on Fresnel as well.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ Is there any set up to do it loyal to that image?

Comment: Just remember that at some point you have to just try it yourself and see what you come up with. We don't have time to stop our projects and make an arbitrary material and light setup. If you can't find the Fresnel effect, or something specific, please ask, but I personally have no time to dig into the Blender Internal render engine and figure it out

Comment: and, to have "really shining" borders, some sort of "beveling" on them helps a lot, since a "perfect" border cannot shine in that way (it's not real).
Otherwise, you have to add them as postprocessing/compositing with some sort of trick...

Comment: @m.ardito thanks, i guess it does have something to do with compositing..

Comment: You should be able to create an effect very similar to this by [using a matcap as your material.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39528/matcap-materials-as-a-material-for-render)

Comment: Thank you both, i already fixed it somehow using a Fresnel material.

Comment: @beavoru If you have a solution please add it as an answer using the answer box below.

Comment: You could also try the rim light/fall-off texture described here: [http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/falloff/](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/falloff/) (You can get the same affect in Cycles with a velvet shader.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution, at least, it's working, but isn't a configuration based on the material, but in the lighting on the scene itself.

Afte creating a regular basic Fresnel texture, with geometry bump added of a texture based on a photography of rocks (on this case) and added two Sun type lamps at the side of the scene based on the position on the camera.

The 'effect' didn't worked at first due to the specular activated, it was too shiny and it even looked like plastic, but after deactiviting it, it worked a lot better, and also i added a little translucency parameter of 0.028.

And the light strenght itself, based on the distance has a parameter of 7.

[image]

Also, as a tip, the effect worked since the camera only 'zooms' into the objects and rotates but following a direct (invisible) line between only two points. Still, i rotated every single DNA object with their respective individual parameters and the effect doesn't change at all, because the position of the lighting also doesn't change.