# Why the texture on my model seems so 'blocky'?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I added a normal texture map plus a geometry bump to my model but when near to the camera, it looks like a lot of little blocks, unlike the real texture that is just an '*organic*' image.

How can i fix this? or is this a bug? i remember a bug with Blender that had to do something with lighting and geometry, affecting the material, but i don't know if this is the case since its the texture.

[image]

Comment: Just looks like a bunch of low res texture artifacts

Comment: I have had similar glitches. It could be (on an unrelated note) something to do with your UV-Unwrap.

Comment: You could try a procedural texture.

Comment: I think after all is a glitch, at least the texture, changed the resolution of the texture by making it as a mosaic, but it still appeared like that.
Then i changed the UVs, scaling the faces in the UV editor, and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @beavoru If you have a solution please add it as an answer using the answer box below.

Comment: I have a solution for the render itself but not for the actual problem, on this actual question/answer you can see it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41755/how-can-i-get-shining-borders-to-a-material-in-blender-render?noredirect=1#comment71290_41755
I don't think thats a solution, not at least to this actual problem since it looks like it can be a bug.