# May i know what are the matcap colors

Tags: matcaps

May i know what are the matcap colors or are they materials. What are the use of that color or material in blender. And if i apply that color or material can it be render in cycles and if not how it works in used cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Matcap stands for Material Capture.

In short: They are fake materials which are intended to help you during the modeling process.

Sometimes using a Matcap instead of the solid shading material in the viewport helps you to spot irregularities in your geometry. If you choose a Matcap similar to the material you have in mind for your final render, it might also help to check if a model will "work" visually.

[image: solid shading and matcap comparsion]

See how the edges and creases show up more prominent when using the matcap?

You can't use them as a final material for your renderings, though.

Comment: great art work. may i know how it is done is that with addon or free hand

Comment: The Matcaps  [can be used for rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39528/matcap-materials-as-a-material-for-render) although they won't provide flexibility because they depend on image already created.

Comment: @atek - I modeled the base shapes and connected the base around them. Then I used multires to carve out the details. It's an old (about 3 years old) mesh I've done for the sole purpose of learning the Blender basics.

Comment: @MrZak - last time I tried, it didn't work. Might be due to the changes in the Transform Vector.

Answer (score 0):

Matcaps are shading modes for the 3D viewport that you can activate in the Properties panel under Shading tab.

They give to all meshes the same viewport shader but they don't have any influence on the materials of the objects when you render in cycles.

Are usually used while sculpting or for hard surface modelling, but also for OpenGL rendering.