# Using ZMT Matcap Files in Blender

Tags: matcaps

Is there a way I can use Zbrush's ZMT matcap files in Blender? I found a lot of very good matcaps on a website for matcaps, but after downloading them it turns out they're all ZMT files, and I cannot find anyway to put these into Blender. Any help would be great.

Comment: Useful to know https://bensimonds.com/2010/07/30/matcap-generator/, helpful workaround http://terrance8d.deviantart.com/journal/Quick-Tip-Using-Custom-Matcaps-in-Blender-538588988

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to learn Cycles more, because that'd be pretty cool to make one myself

Comment: FYI http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39528/matcap-materials-as-a-material-for-render

Comment: Yep, I already know how to apply custom matcaps the "ghetto" way, but I was wondering if I could use the ZBrush ones because I love the way they look and how high the resolutions are.