# Are matcaps renderable?

Tags: rendering, matcaps

Why can't I see matcaps having pressed F12? I have them in the 3D View but the render shows just the "basic" material.

Comment: «Matcaps» are images mapped on a normal. It provides a quick way to define visible material properties for modeling and sculpting. Because Matcap rendering fully bypasses the material shader code, it’s a very fast rendering option.Essentially, matcaps are just to help you visualize the shape, reflections and crevices in the viewport and not for rendering.If you wish to use them for rendering check out this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39528/matcap-materials-as-a-material-for-render

Comment: What Teja said, plus you can render Matcaps using Open GL rendering option instead of F12. Go to Render>Open GL Render Image.

Comment: @Teja: I use pre-installed matcaps. Pressed N, checked the "matcap" option in the Shading part, selected one. What should I do next?

Comment: @Mzidare: I prefer F12 rendering